# find object key in nested array object

Tags: javascript, object, indexof

I have an object I would get `{FIABILITE:XXX,RECTIVITE:YYY}` of `region=AAA` ( or other) in `VOYAGES` ( I dont need to search in `ICC` )

Here's how I'm trying to get data

```js
const activityName = 'VOYAGES' // activityName: VOYAGES Or ICC
const  queryParams = [',','region=AAA']
const objectifs = {
  'VOYAGES': [
    {
      'region=AAA': {
        FIABILITE: '75',
        REACTIVITE: '90'
      }
    },
    {
      'region=BBBB': {
        FIABILITE: '75',
        REACTIVITE: '86'
      }
    }
  ],
  'ICC': [
    {
      'region=CSIC': {
        FIABILITE: '45',
        REACTIVITE: '80'
      }
    }
  ]
}


const objKeys = Object.values(objectifs[activityName])
const index = objKeys.indexOf((queryParams[1]));
const data = objectifs[activityName][index]; 
console.log(data)
```

Actualy `data` is undefined.

I want to get `{FIABILITE:XXX,RECTIVITE:YYY}` of `region=AAA` for example

Comment: what exactly  you want?

Comment: how do you define which region you want? by user input, by hardcoding, or how?

Comment: Ye it's user input , so dynamic

Comment: I don't exactly understand, what output do you expect? What do you need? What is going wrong exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of how your object is created that you're getting undefined, you need to add an index `objectifs['VOYAGES'][0]['region=AAA']` as so :

```js
objectifs = {
  'VOYAGES': [{
      'region=AAA': {
        FIABILITE: '75',
        REACTIVITE: '90'
      }
    },
    {
      'region=BBBB': {
        FIABILITE: '75',
        REACTIVITE: '86'
      }
    }
  ],
  'ICC': [{
    'region=CSIC': {
      FIABILITE: '45',
      REACTIVITE: '80'
    }
  }]
}
var data = {}

objectifs['VOYAGES'].forEach(function(element) {
  if ('region=AAA' in element) {
    data = element['region=AAA'];
  }
});

console.log(data)
```

Comment: you hard coded the index `0` I would find it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```js
const queryParams = [',','region=AAA']
const activityName = 'VOYAGES' 
const searchKey = queryParams[1];

objectif={'VOYAGES': [
    {
        'region=AAA': {
            FIABILITE: '75',
            REACTIVITE: '90'
        }
    },
    {
        'region=BBBB': {
            FIABILITE: '75',
            REACTIVITE: '86'
        }
    }
],
'ICC': [
    {
        'region=CSIC': {
            FIABILITE: '45',
            REACTIVITE: '80'
        }
    }
]};

let resultData = objectif[activityName].find((entry) => {
  return entry[searchKey];
})[searchKey];

console.log("Result data: ", resultData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `index` in the array of the object with a specific property using:

`const index = objectifs[activityName].findIndex(x => !!x[queryParams[1]])`

Working Example:

```js
const activityName = 'VOYAGES' // activityName: VOYAGES Or ICC
const  queryParams = [',','region=AAA']
const objectifs = {
  'VOYAGES': [
    {
      'region=AAA': {
        FIABILITE: '75',
        REACTIVITE: '90'
      }
    },
    {
      'region=BBBB': {
        FIABILITE: '75',
        REACTIVITE: '86'
      }
    }
  ],
  'ICC': [
    {
      'region=CSIC': {
        FIABILITE: '45',
        REACTIVITE: '80'
      }
    }
  ]
}

const index = objectifs[activityName].findIndex(x => x.hasOwnProperty([queryParams[1]]));

const data = objectifs[activityName][index]; 
console.log(data)

const obj = data[queryParams[1]];
console.log(obj)
```